# Equal operator in Postfix expression

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm evaluating `postfix` expression in c++. Everything is working fine but I've not managed the `=`equal operator properly.

The Problem causing Infix Expression look like this: `A = 2 + B = 5` where A and B are variables.
My program convert it into postfix as: `2 5 = B + = A`.

In my program I wrote that `if current element is an equal operator followed by a variable then move the result in that variable.` Which is not proper way to do because my program after solving the above expression gives `B = 5` and `A = 7` which seems wrong from the expression.

Which technique should I follow to handle the equal operator for my code?

Comment: I assume that by "equal operator" you actually mean "*assignment* operator"? Then the results seems to be consistent with the expression you have: You assign `5` to `B`, then you take `B` and add `2` and assign the result (`7`) to `A`.

Comment: I concur with Joachim. The assignment operator is inverse in the sense that it first reads the expression and then the assignee (which is correct). Maybe is this what creates some confusion because we are used to the direct assignment x = 3 + 4.

Comment: What did you expect to see as a result?

Comment: I was confused that in `A = 2 + B = 5`  `2 + B would be solved separately and it will omit the 5 because left hand side is a constant and finally the answer of 2+B will be assigned to A.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, the answer you get is consistent with the rule *If current element is an equal operator followed by a variable then move the result in that variable*.

However, there is something in the rule that breaks the uniformity of the postfix notation, so I would rather recommend changing that rule to

*If the current element is an assignment operator then move the first operand (anything) to the second operand (variable)*

For this rule to be applicable you have to validate that the last token (second operand) is a variable.

The rule I propose is consistent with other operations. For instance the postfix notation `3 4 +` is converted to `3 + 4` because by the time your scanner reads `+` it will take the last two operands, `3` and `4`, and sum them: `3 + 4`. In the same way `3 4 + A =` would proceed by first saving `3 + 4` as the first operand, then `A` as the second and finally moving the first operand to the second `A = 3 + 4`. Instead, the way you devised the assignment rule is special in that it first reads the operator `=` and then the second operand `A`, which will work, but not in the same way as the rest of the operations.

Comment: okay I got your rule, but What will happen if `A = B + 2 = 5`?

Comment: If you change the rule, the expression `A = B + 2 = 5` will not be valid because it was produced with the other rule. If you adopt my proposal of making the rule uniform you now have to impose the existence of two operands before reading `=`, as much as `3 *` is invalid just because `*` requires 2 arguments. In other words, `A B =` will become valid and `A = B` invalid.